# Copying only text files into new folder in R

Tags: r, text, analytics

I have a folder of PDFs that I am supposed to perform text analytics on within R. Thus far the best method of doing so has been using R to convert these files to text files using pdftotext. After this however I am unable to perform any analytics as the text files are placed into the same folder as the PDFs from which they are derived.

I am achieving this through:

```
dest <- "C:/PDF" 
myfiles <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "pdf", full.names = TRUE) 
lapply(myfiles, function(i) system(paste('"C:/xpdfbin-win-3.04/bin64/pdftotext.exe"', paste0('"',i,'"')), wait= FALSE))
```

I was wondering the best method of retaining only the text files, whether it be saving them to a newly created folder in this step or if more must be done.

I have tried:

```
dir.create("C:/txtfiles")
new.folder <- "C:/txtfiles"
dest <- "C:/PDF"
list.of.files <-list.files(dest, ".txt$")
file.copy(list.of.files, new.folder)
```

However this only fills the new folder 'txtfiles' with blank text files named after the ones created by the first few lines of code.

Comment: A command like your file.copy works for me.  Try with argument `overwrite = TRUE` or first removing the empty files; maybe once the empty files were placed there and they are not being overwritten.

Comment: Call the files something besides `i`, which is their current name. If you want them in another folder, put in the path there. [Documentation.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following code:

```
files <- list.files(path="current folder location",pattern = "\\.txt$")  #lists all .txt files
for(i in 1:length(files)){
    file.copy(from=paste("~/current folder location/",files[i],sep=""), 
          to="destination folder")
```

This should copy all text files in "current folder location" into a separate folder "destination folder".

Comment: Thank you for the help, however I keep getting an error saying 'allFiles[i]' could not being found; what object should I be placing there/what is the function of 'allFiles[i]' within the code?

Comment: @Fikucki ooops, my bad. replace allFiles with files. I will edit my response above.